# Using a variable for a file path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am very new to writing batch files, but I am trying to automate some data updating I have to do. I have the pdftotext.exe in a folder with a pdf file that I get each month. I was hoping to use a wildcard in the batch file so that I don't have to change the code each month. So right now I run:

```
pdftotext -raw -nopgbrk CO_Aug16.pdf
```

This will run the conversion with the pdf and the executable in the same folder, but if I try to use a wildcard in the filename:

```
pdftotext -raw -nopgbrk CO*.pdf
```

It looks for a file named that way, so I tried to create a variable called fname and put the wildcard in that name, but when I run:

```
set fname = "C:\Users\...\CO*.pdf"
pdftotext -raw -nopgbrk "%fname%"
```

It acts like it is trying to open a blank file, I get:

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file ''
```

Is it possible for me to be able to use the wildcard? Sorry if this is a basic question, I just started learning to write in a batch file for this project.

Comment: Start by removing the spaces on both sides of the `=` in your `set` statement, so that it reads `set fname="C:\Users\...\CO*.pdf"` (of course using an actual valid path to the file). Does that change anything?

Comment: That at least gets it to look at the file but says it can't find the file, assuming because it won't take the wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling of wildcards is done by the applications, not by the terminal.

The approach I use is to find the files using `dir *.pdf` and then for each file call the command.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do pdftotext -raw -nopgbrk "%%~f"
```

If you're entering this in a batch file use 2 percentage signs. If you're writing direct into `cmd` then just use 1.

Description:

- For /F - run a command for each line of another commands output
- tokens = * - Put all the line content into %f
- dir /b *.pdf = the command we loop over. Finds all pdfs. Only outputs the minimum of data.
- Your command - the %%~f is the filename. The ~ strips any quote marks

Comment: When you put dir /b *.pdf, should dir be my directory, so C:\Users\.., where the file is at? Because I get an error when I try that

Comment: No, `dir` is a command that lists the contents of a directory. In this case it's referering to the current working directory of the script. To look for another directory do `dir /b c:\users\myuser\hisFolder\*.pdf`

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thanks for the explanation and for laying out what each part does, that helps me understand it a lot more.

Comment: I know this is a bit delayed from when I originally asked this, but I had everything in the same directory so I didn't need look for another directory. But now to try and clean things up a bit I tried to put them in another folder, but I am getting `code`(The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Sorry for the error in the comment, the message is `The system cannot find the file specified` and `The system cannot find the path specified`